# Vectorizing: plotting multiple contours with geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm writing code to create multiple data sets of contours. My steps are:

1. Generate raw data with

   `T<-runif()`
2. Write functions to describe a contour described by parameteric functions:

   - `x<-function(t)`
   - `y<-function(t)`
3. Convert vectors of real numbers `x,y` to complex numbers `x + 1i*y`
4. Apply a complex function on the data, for example,

   `sin`
5. Extract the real and imaginary parts into sets of real numbers

   `fx, fy`.
6. Plot the pairs `

   `geom_path(x=fx,y=fy)`
7. color code it with a vector of colors

I've been reusing the code every time I want to draw a contour, but I'd like to vectorize it so I can minimize the repetition on my code. How can I do that?

Here's an example:

```
  #Create data

  #the parameter:
  T<-sort(runif(100,min=-1, max=1))


  #x(t), y(t)
  xt.hor<-function(t,c){
    return(c)
  }
  yt<-function(t,scale){
    return (scale*t)
  }


  X1<-mapply(xt.hor,T,c=-10)
  # X2, X3, X4
  X5<-mapply(xt.hor,T,c=10)

  YHor<-mapply(yt,T,scale=10)

  df1<-data.frame(x1=X1,
                  #x2,x3,x4,
                  x5=X5,yh=YHor)


  #convert to complex numbers:

  toComplex<-function(x,y){complex(real=x,imaginary=y)}

  z1<-mapply(toComplex,df1$x1,y=df1$yh)
  #z2, z3, z4
  z5<-mapply(toComplex,df1$x5,y=df1$yh)

  fz1<-sapply(z1,sin)
  #fz2,fz3,fz4
  fz5<-sapply(z5,sin)

  fx1<-sapply(fz1,Re)
  #fx2,fx3,fx4
  fx5<-sapply(fz5,Re)

  fy1<-sapply(fz1,Im)
  #fy2,fy3,fy4
  fy5<-sapply(fz5,Im)

  df2<-data.frame(fx1=fx1,fy1=fy1,
                  #curve2, curve 3, curve 4
                  fx5=fx5,fy5=fy5)

  RedOrgVector<-c('#fd8d3c','#fc4e2a','#e31a1c','#bd0026','#800026')

  p <- ggplot(data = df2)

  p+xlim(c(-10,10))+ylim(c(-10,10))+
    geom_path(x=fx1,y=fy1,size=.75,color=RedOrgVector[1],linetype=1)+
    #curve2, curve3, curve4
    geom_path(x=fx5,y=fy5,size=.75,color=RedOrgVector[5],linetype=1)
```

Comment: BTW `toComplex` is vectorised, no need for mapply

Comment: same for the following `sapply` lines as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using the `tidyverse`.  Most of your code could be condensed into a function that simply builds and transforms the supplied data into a format that `ggplot2` likes.

The `generate_curve` function does just that.  Takes an input vector and parameters (c, scale and the curve number, n) and returns a `tibble` (fancy data frame) of x, y and a curve number.

How you would get multiple curves is by generating multiple input vectors (via `rerun` and using `purrr` or `mapply` to map the `generate_curve` function to each vector. In this case I'm using `pmap_df` from purr, which maps a function to a list of inputs and returns a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

generate_curve <- function(data, c, scale, n) {

  tibble(X = c,
         YHor = scale*data,
         z = complex(real = X, imaginary = YHor),
         fz = sin(z),
         fx = Re(fz),
         fy = Im(fz)) %>% 
    select(fx, fy) %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
    gather(group, value, -row) %>% 
    extract(group, "var", regex = "f(\\w)") %>% 
    spread(var, value) %>% 
    mutate(curve = n) %>% 
    select(-row)
}

list <- rerun(4, sort(runif(100, min = -1, max = 1)))
cs <- c(10,5,-5,-10)
scale <- rep(10,4)
length <- seq_along(list)

curves <- pmap_df(list(list,cs,scale,length), generate_curve)

RedOrgVector <- c('#fd8d3c','#fc4e2a','#e31a1c','#bd0026','#800026')

ggplot(curves, aes(x = x, y = y, group = factor(curve))) +
  geom_path(aes(color = factor(curve)), linetype = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(RedOrgVector, c(1:5))) +
  xlim(c(-10,10)) +
  ylim(c(-10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Is this functional programming? I didn't know ``R`` could work this way! Neat!

Comment: I'm following most of your code, but please explain ``spread(var, value)``

Comment: `spread` takes the distinct values of `var` and moves them into columns, populating each rows with the value of `value`. https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/